# Supporting specific device orientation in a iOS library - one place change

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an application with multiple view controllers in it. I need to share the library for the same. My application only supports landscape mode. Do I need to implement the below method in all my view controllers to return only landscape mode or is there any once place change that I can do for my library. For independent app I know we can set it in the info.plist but that option is not here with library. Any suggestions?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, sort of.

View controllers embedded in things like a Navigation Controller or a Tab Bar Controller rotate according to that controller.  If your entire app is nested inside a Tab Bar Controller, for example, you can subclass Tab Bar Controller and override those methods, and now your entire app follows those rules because the root controller dictates the rotation rules.

But if you're displaying views modally, the modal views will have their own rotation rules.

The easiest thing I can think to do would be to subclass UIViewController and override these methods (and ONLY override these methods).  Now make every other one of your view controllers a subclass of this subclass.  Now your view controllers all follow the logic you wrote in their super class.

Comment: So my app is mostly navigation controller based app with multiple places I show view controllers modally with each view controller having its own nav bar controller. Shall I subclass navigation controller or UIViewController?

Comment: So, it's a Navigation Controller that modally presents other Navigation controller?  Is there any view controller that's not in a Navigation Controller?

Comment: No. Every viewcontroller has navigation controller in it.

Comment: In this case, you only need to subclass UINavigationController, override the rotation methods, and make all your navigation controllers use this class.